# Grafana, Prometheus, Kiali authentication with AzureAD and istio internal load balancer

Tags: azure, prometheus, grafana, istio

I’m deploying istio in azure kubernetes services (AKS) and I have the following question:

Is it possible to deploy istio using an internal load balancer. Looks like it is deployed in Azure with a public load balancer by default. What do I need to change to make it use an internal load balancer?

Comment: why do you have 2 individual questions in a single post? they are not even connected in any fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second question :

It is possible to add AKS annotation for an internal load balancer according to AKS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb):

> To create an internal load balancer, create a service manifest named `internal-lb.yaml` with the service type *LoadBalancer* and the `azure-load-balancer-internal` annotation as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: internal-app
>   annotations:
>     service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
> spec:
>   type: LoadBalancer
>   ports:
>   - port: 80
>   selector:
>     app: internal-app
> ```

So You can set this annotation by using helm with the following --set:

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.serviceAnnotations.'service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal'="true" > aks-istio.yaml
```

---

As mentioned in comment You should stick to One question per post as advised [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). So I suggest creating second post with other question.

Hope it helps.

---

**Update:**

For istioctl You can do the following:

1. Generate manifest file for Your istio deployment for this example I used demo profile.

```
istioctl manifest generate --set profile=demo > istio.yaml
```

2. Modify the `istio.yaml` and search for text for `type: LoadBalancer`.

```
---


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    release: istio
    istio: ingressgateway
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
  ports:
```

Add the annotation for the internal load balancer like this:

```
---


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    release: istio
    istio: ingressgateway
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
  ports:
```

3. After saving changes deploy modified `istio.yaml` to Your K8s cluster using:

```
kubectl apply -f istio.yaml
```

After that You can verify if annotation is present in `istio-ingressgateway` `service`.

```
$ kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal":"true"},"labels":{"app":"istio-ingressgateway","istio":"ingressgateway","release":"istio"},"name":"istio-ingressgateway","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"status-port","port":15020,"targetPort":15020},{"name":"http2","port":80,"targetPort":80},{"name":"https","port":443},{"name":"kiali","port":15029,"targetPort":15029},{"name":"prometheus","port":15030,"targetPort":15030},{"name":"grafana","port":15031,"targetPort":15031},{"name":"tracing","port":15032,"targetPort":15032},{"name":"tls","port":15443,"targetPort":15443}],"selector":{"app":"istio-ingressgateway"},"type":"LoadBalancer"}}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-01-27T13:51:07Z"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the community guidelines. I will ask the authentication questions separately. I'm not using helm. Would you know how I can accomplish this using istioctl?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include solution for istioctl.

Comment: I was not able to run this command in the windows box as I kept getting the following error message:  
`Could not configure logs: couldn't open sink "/dev/null"`  
However, I was finally able to make it work by installing istio-init using helm. Then I ran  `helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.serviceAnnotations.'service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal'="true" > aks-istio.yaml`  replaced the annotations for internal load balancer and then used kubectl to install the manifest.